# Print each line multiple but different times

Tags: large-files

I have a huge file, ~4000000 lines that look like that:

file:

```
1 
1 
2 
3 
2 
4 
...
```

basically, each line contains a number.
Considering this example I would like to generate a file that will look as follows:

newFile:

```
1 
1 
2 
2 
3 
3 
3 
2 
2 
4 
4 
4 
4 
....
```

I would like that each line to be repeated n times when n is the number stored in the original line.

As I mentioned, the file is very large so Im looking for the fastest way to do so. I think that currently, with the code I implemented the bottleneck is the fact that I need to reopen the new file for writing.

This is how Im doing it now but its very very slow

```
while read i; do seq 1 ${i} | xargs -i -- echo $i >> newFile ;done < file
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't this just plain sorting?

Comment: @Braiam no, the output is much bigger than the input; and the output isn't sorted, in the example there are two `2` lines appearing after `3`...

Answer (score 7):

In `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= $1; i++) { print $0 } }' file > newFile
```

This will read the input file once and write the output file once, never needing to re-open anything.

Answer (score 7):

In `perl`, using the `x` string repetition operator:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $_ x $_' file
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
2
2
4
4
4
4
```